# NodeJS & electron and import

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm trying to use `import` clause in Electron app. I have the most basic setup

```
1/ npm init
2/ npm i -D electron@latest
```

that's it

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "electron-stable",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^13.2.2"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import {app, BrowserWindow, Menu, ipcRenderer} from 'electron';
```

and I get en error (`npm run start`):

```
[Window Title]
Error

[Main Instruction]
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process

[Content]
Uncaught Exception:
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: E:\work\node.js\_tests\electron\electron-stable\index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of E:\work\node.js\_tests\electron\electron-stable\index.js from E:\work\node.js\_tests\electron\electron-stable\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from E:\work\node.js\_tests\electron\electron-stable\package.json.

    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1096:13)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:935:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:14)
    at Function.f._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12913)
    at loadApplicationPackage (E:\work\node.js\_tests\electron\electron-stable\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:110:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\work\node.js\_tests\electron\electron-stable\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:222:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1078:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1108:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:935:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:14)

[OK]
```

1. I've tried to have / not have `"type": "module"`
2. I've tried to play with file name extension (js, mjs)
3. I do NOT want to use require (I know it works)
4. I do NOT want to rely on 3rd party package/bundler/tool

Is there a way to do it natively or is there some issue with electron?
Thanks

Comment: Same problem here.  Node 16.8.0 Electron 14.0.0

Comment: Although it is too late but for newbies I am leaving a [link](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21457#issuecomment-1099904505) which could be little time saving for them. In a nutshell, the `import something from "some-package"` syntax or esm is completely incompatible with ElectronJS. So cjs or require syntax is the only option